# ¿Como Instalar Jupyter lab en en otra Unidad diferente de C:?

Tags: python, cmd, jupyter, anaconda

Tengo Instalado Jupyter lab 3.x como parte de los paquetes de sistemas Anaconda en una Unidad D: diferente de C:
ejecutando:

```
`jupyter lab --paths`
```

Obtengo:

config:

```
C:\Users\name\.jupyter
C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\Python\etc\jupyter
D:\Anaconda\etc\jupyter
C:\ProgramData\jupyter
```

data:

```
C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\jupyter
C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\Python\share\jupyter
D:\Anaconda\share\jupyter
C:\ProgramData\jupyter
```

runtime:

```
C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime
```

He instalado Python desde python.org en otra unidad H:. Y he instalado jupyter lab version 4.1 en un un entorno aislado de la base :

```
`python -m env juptyter_4`
```

Ejecutando: `jupyter lab --paths`

`(jupyter_4) PS H:\envs_jobs> jupyter --paths`

config:

```
H:\envs_jobs\jupyter_4\etc\jupyter
C:\Users\name\.jupyter
C:\ProgramData\jupyter
```

data:

```
H:\envs_jobs\jupyter_4\share\jupyter
C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\jupyter
C:\ProgramData\jupyter
```

runtime:

```
C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime
```

Como se ve tambien ha instalado carpetas y archivos en C: lo que no deseo, pues al abrir jupyter en el environment jupyter_4, salen errores de lanzamiento:

`Failed validating 'additionalProperties' in schema:`

Hay alguna forma de instalar jupyter lab 4 completamente en la unidad H, sin que instale carpetas y archivos en \Users o \ProgramData de la Undad C:?